# Show shipping amount for entire order in custom report Magento2

Tags: magento2, grid, custom-reports

I have created the custom sales report,

used below code in my listing.xml file,

```
<column name="shipping_amount">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Amount</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

I am loading the collection from table **"sales_order"**

This will load the shipping amount column in the Grid,

Here my issue is, I have one order **#000000001**  which has 3 items,

Sku, 1000, 1001, 1002,

So 3 records are shown in the grid with the shipping amount of 50 for each item which is not correct,

So can we show shipping_amount in the last row of the order record,

is something like that possible?

This is the example pic,

[image]

Please anyone suggest me how this can be achieved. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have work around it and able to do as like below.

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/listing.xml**

```
<column name="shipping_amount_custom" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Amount" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Amount</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Then,
 **Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Amount.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository as StockItem;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as Product;

class Amount extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {
    protected $_orderObj;
    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
      array $components = [],
      array $data = []
    ){
      $this->_orderObj = $orderObj;
      parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
     }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();           
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) { 
          $productSku = $item['sku'];
          $order_id = $item['order_id'];
          $lastOrderItemSku = $this->getLastOrderItemDetails($order_id);
          if(isset($lastOrderItemSku) && $lastOrderItemSku == $productSku){
                $lastItemShippingAmt = $item['shipping_amount'];
            }else{
                $lastItemShippingAmt = '';
            }
          $item['shipping_amount_custom'] = $lastItemShippingAmt;
        }
      }
      return $dataSource;
    }

   public function getLastOrderItemDetails($orderId){       
     $orders = $this->_orderObj->load($orderId);
     $numItems = count($orders->getAllItems());     
     $i = 0;
     foreach ($orders->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if(++$i === $numItems) {
            $lastItemSku = $item->getSku();             
            return $lastItemSku;
         }
       }        
       return '';           
    }

}
```

**Hope this will help Others. Cheers!!.**